# Terracotta 4.3 - jar conflicts

Tags: terracotta, ehcache-bigmemory

I am trying to configure terracotta 4.3 with my application. I have done all the necessary changes but when i start my tomcat server, i get the below error(in bold). Can someone suggest how do i go about resolving it. Please note that i cannot exclude jaxrs-api.jar as it is needed for external rest calls.

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
>   instance of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'pendingAccountCacheManager' defined in URL
>   [file:/C:/dev/apache-tomcat-7.0.16_1/webapps/account/WEB-INF/classes/context/account-cacheloader.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Failed to instantiate ManagementServer.
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Failed to instantiate ManagementServer.
>     at
>   net.sf.ehcache.management.ManagementServerLoader.register(ManagementServerLoader.java:140)
>     at
>   net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.initializeManagementService(CacheManager.java:553)
>     at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.doInit(CacheManager.java:516)    at
>   net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:395)   at
>   net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.(CacheManager.java:356)     at
>   org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.java:138)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
>     ... 20 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   net.sf.ehcache.management.ManagementServerLoader$ManagementServerHolder.start(ManagementServerLoader.java:215)
>     at
>   net.sf.ehcache.management.ManagementServerLoader.register(ManagementServerLoader.java:125)
>     ... 27 more
>   **Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to castjar:file:/C:/dev/apache-tomcat-7.0.16_1/webapps/pendingaccount/WEB-INF/lib/jaxrs-api-3.0.9.Final.jar!/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class
>   to
>   jar:file:/C:/dev/apache-tomcat-7.0.16_1/webapps/pendingaccount/WEB-INF/lib/ehcache-ee-2.10.0.0.26.jar!/rest-management-private-classpath/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class_terracotta
>     at
>   javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:97)**
>     at
>   com.terracotta.management.security.impl.JerseyIdentityAssertionServiceClient.(JerseyIdentityAssertionServiceClient.java:67)
>     at
>   net.sf.ehcache.management.ManagementServerImplEE.loadEmbeddedAgentServiceLocator(ManagementServerImplEE.java:132)
>     at
>   net.sf.ehcache.management.ManagementServerImplEE.initialize(ManagementServerImplEE.java:71)
>     at
>   net.sf.ehcache.management.ManagementServerImplEE.initialize(ManagementServerImplEE.java:184)
>     ... 33 more

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this,I added the ehcache-ee-2.10.0.0.26.jar and other terracotta related jars into the endorsed folder of tomcat. This helped resolve the issue of conflicting jars.

Comment: Hello,you should not need to move the terracotta jars to the endorsed folder of tomcat. This looks like a bug in the Terracotta management code. I work for Terracotta, I just created a Jira to follow progress on the resolution of this issue : https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/CDV-1669

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyDahanne. For now endorsed folder is the only option. But once the issue is resolved i would try again